# World vs Include in cucumber/ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Can anyone tell me the difference between include and World? in my env.rb file I want to expose a module, and I can't really see the difference between the approaches...

Module example:

```
module Test do
  ...
end
```

In my env.rb file:

```
World(Test)
```

or

```
include Test
```

Besides that, can anyone state the pros/cons of using World rather than include in cucumber/ruby?

Answer (score 1):

World(Test) is the preferred method.

The purpose to using World(Test) is that you don't pollute the global namespace yet you still have all the functionality of that module available in your stepdefs.

Comment: Although, if I do World(Test), I can use the module's methods across other portions of my framework, and not exclusively to my step definitions... but maybe a learning is keep the consistency where World is meant to give visibility of helpers to my step definition... that should be the pattern I guess...